# Prove divisibility is a partial order relation over natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have proceeded like this so far:

(The natural number set includes $0$)

Reflexivity:
Proof: $a = k \cdot a,$ since $k$ also belongs to natural number, it is proved.

Anti-symmetry:
$a \mid b$ means $a = k_1 \cdot b$ and $b \mid a$ means $b = k_2 \cdot a$. Now, $a = k_1\cdot k_2\cdot a.$ This means $a = b.$

Transitivity:
Not sure how to prove this.

I know it holds but not sure how it can be shown mathematically.

Comment: Shouldn't it have reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive property?

Answer (score 4):

Well if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c,$ then $b=da$ and $c=eb$ for some natural numbers $d,e,$ and so $c=....$ can you take it from there?

Your reflexivity proof needs fixed, though. What is $k$?

Also, I would add a bit to your antisymmetry proof. Since $a=k_1k_2a,$ then $k_1k_2=1$ if $a\ne 0,$ so since $k_1,k_2$ are naturals, then $k_1=1,$ and so $a=b$ as desired. Now, in the case that $a=0,$ we must proceed a bit differently: since $a\mid b,$ then we have $b=k_2a=0$ directly.

Comment: but why k1,k2 = 1 ? why not zero?

Comment: That's a good point, actually. I forgot zero was an element for you. Let me amend my answer to address that.

Comment: @SebastianSantana If $k_1$ or $k_2$ is zero, then $k_1k_2=0$, not $1$.

Comment: @Sebastian: My answer is updated. Does it make sense now?

Comment: great ! thanks !

Comment: how can i improve my reflexivity proof?

Comment: @Sebastian: You must answer my question. What is $k?$

Comment: It is natural number

Comment: You are *trying* to show that for each natural number $a$, there is a natural number $k$ such that $a=ka.$ You can't just assume it's true. What is $k$? Be *specific*.

Comment: because that is by the definition of divides. a div b means b = k . a

Comment: I know. But you are *trying* to show that $a\mid a$ for all natural numbers $a$. You can't just assume it.

Comment: Phew ! Not sure what I'm missing and the proof should look like

Comment: Think about it. What is $k$? Be ***specific***. It isn't enough to just *say* it's a natural number.

Comment: Not sure. That is the end of my mathematical ability

Comment: Well, you're trying to show that there is some $k$ such that $$a=ka.$$ Solve for $k$.

Comment: @Sebastian If it helps, rewrite it as $0=ka-a,$ so that $0=(k-1)a.$ All we know about $a$ is that it's some natural number, so what does $k-1$ ***have*** to be? What, then, is $k$?

Comment: @Sebastian: There's one last thing you can try if you're still stuck. Pick several example values of $a$ and try to find a $k$ for each of them. See if it gives you an idea for how to do the proof of reflexivity.

Comment: k is a divisor, did I get it right?

Comment: You keep focusing on what *kind* of thing $k$ needs to be, but you still haven't figured out what $k$ actually *is*. Follow my last suggestion, and try several examples for $a$. If you already did that, can you share a few with me?

Answer (score 0):

Since $a \mid b \implies a=sb, s \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}$ 
And $b \mid c \implies b=tc t \in \mathbb{N} \tag{2}$ 
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ 
$$a=sb=s(tc) = (st)c = uc$$
, where $u = st \in \mathbb{N}$.
Hence $a=uc \implies a \mid c$.