# Let X := {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43} be ordered by divisibility. Find the maximal and minimal elements of X.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, maximal-subgroup

What does it mean that X is ordered by divisibility when all elements of X are prime numbers? Also doesn't there have to be some partial ordering relation for there to be maximal and minimal elements? Thanks in advance for any clarifying answers.

Comment: What is your definition of "ordered by divisibility"? Indeed, we need a partial ordering. Did you search already? Do it, and see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267908/prove-divisibility-is-a-partial-order-relation-over-natural-numbers).

Comment: Yes, I tried to search for a definition of "ordered by divisibility", but couldn't find anything. The question is from a maths exercise in school, and i found it wierd that the quiestion was so unclear. thnx for the link!

Comment: The divisibility relation is transitive, so it doesn't take much effort to work out how it might be interpreted as a partial ordering.  But that leaves ambiguous whether $d\mid k$ is meant to be interpreted as $d\le k$ or as $d\ge k$.  It would follow that the resulting sets of minimal and maximal elements might be switched in an erroneous interpretation.  So the person who assigned this "maths exercise in school" would be the best judge.  The title poses a problem not further presented in the body of your Question; a clarifying edit is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a set $X\subseteq \mathbb Z^+$ you can introduce a partial order
$$a \preceq b \Leftrightarrow a|b$$
(Of course you can reverse this relation, what changes the notion of swaps the notions of maximal and minimal elements).

Recall that $m\in X$ is a [maximal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements) if there is no element greater than $m$. In this case it means that $m$ does not divide any other element of $X$. If $X$ consists of prime numbers only, this means that *every* element is maximal.

I leave minimal elements as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, think I'll be able to find the minimal elements!